# Not able to import story in vue component

Tags: vue.js, storybook

I have made a story component looking like (FilterCheckbox.js):

```
export default {
 name: 'filter-checkbox',
 props: ['options'],

 data() {
  return {
    text: this.$props.options
  }
 },

 watch: {
  options: function () {
   this.text = this.$props.options;
  }
 },

 template: `
  <label class="pure-material-checkbox">
    <input class="filterAllInput" type="checkbox" @click="onChange">
    <span> {{text}} </span>
  </label>
 `,

 methods: {
  onChange() {
   this.$emit('change');
  },
 },
};
```

Its a checkbox with text and its own style.
Now I want to use it in a component looking like this (Filters.vue):

```
<template>
 <div>
   <filter-checkbox @change="onChangeWhenFilterIsChoosen()" :options="options"></filter-checkbox>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import FilterCheckbox from './../../stories/FilterCheckbox';
name: 'Filters',
components: { FilterCheckbox },
data: () => ({
 options: 'test text'
}),

methods: {

 onChangeWhenFilterIsChoosen: function () {

 }

},

</script>
```

Somehow the import is not working and the story component is not showing in my other component. What am I doing wrong?

**new:**
I have now made a stories.js called: 1-Filter.stories.js:

```
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions';
import FilterCheckbox from './FilterCheckbox';

export default {
 title: 'Checkbox',
};

export const text = () => ({
components: { FilterCheckbox },
data() {
 return {
    options: '12 Liter'
 }
},
template: '<filter-checkbox @change="action" :options="options"> 
 </filter-checkbox>',
  methods: { action: action('Changed') },
});
```

thats implements the filter-checkbox just fine. But still not working in the other component.

Comment: Is import working? Did you console.log it after import?

Because I see a different problem

Comment: Yes, in the console.log it looks like this: {"name":"filter-checkbox","props":["options"],"watch":{},"template":"\n \n\n    <label class=\"pure-material-checkbox\">\n      <input class=\"filterAllInput\" type=\"checkbox\" @click=\"onChange\">\n      <span> {{text}} </span>\n    </label>\n  ","methods":{}}

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: There is no errors in the console.log :-S

Answer (score 0):

Please update your `Filters` component with this;

```
<script>
import FilterCheckbox from './../../stories/FilterCheckbox';
export default {

 name: 'filters',
 components: { filterCheckbox: FilterCheckbox },
 data: () => ({
  options: 'test text'
 }),

 methods: {

  onChangeWhenFilterIsChoosen: function () {
   //
  }

 },
}

</script>
```

Comment: Check the `created` hook in `filter-checkbox` component, if it's working and check logs.

Comment: I have tried and there is not an error. I have updated my question with a stories.js I have made and that implements the <filter-checkbox> just fine. You can se it in the question.